# Preventing the same form from being sent from 2 or more devices

Tags: laravel

This issue has taken a considerable amount of my time. I have prevented the simultaneous login from multiple devices using Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->password), but this is not a definitive solution. Even on the same device, users can submit the form simultaneously by clicking quickly or using a script to submit the form.

Interestingly, even with throttle:1,1, the issue is bypassed due to simultaneous posts within milliseconds. Feel free to try it:

For example, let's say we want to deduct 10 points from a user's balance.

Device 1
Request: ----
Device 2
Request: ----
Device 3
Request: ----
All three requests are submitted simultaneously by clicking the form at the same time. In the controller, $currentBalanceQuery is working simultaneously on the server, returning a balance of 20 points. A simple operation subtracts 10 points, resulting in an update of 20 - 10 = 10. This operation is performed for all three requests simultaneously.

As a result, the user's balance becomes -10 points.

I hope I have been able to explain my problem. If there is anyone who has experienced and solved this issue, could they please provide assistance?

Comment: Instead of focusing on preventing form submissions, think about preventing the underlying business logic that occurs. A common way to do that is with locking. [Here's an article](https://www.moderntreasury.com/journal/designing-ledgers-with-optimistic-locking) where they use optimistic locking to protect against concurrent requests.